# Mouse cursor does not 'stick' to silverlight scrollbar control

Tags: c#, silverlight, scrollbar

I'm using the silverlight scrollbar and I'm finding that the mouse does not drag the scrollbar 1:1. When I drag downwards for instance I find the mouse cursor starts going down further than the scrollbar has..

edit: this issue occurs in IE8 but not Firefox 5.

Comment: Is this happening in every single Silverlight app or just in a specific one?

Comment: @meds: do you have a simplified case in Xaml we can try? Also, as Erno says, is it consistent across all browsers?

Comment: @HiTech Magic the problem only occurs on IE8, on Firefox it's fine. The scrollbar handle sticks to the cursor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working with datasets or trying to display large, complex data within the object whatever the scrollbar is attached to?

If yes, try toggling UI virtualization and see if it changes anything.

If it doesn't work it may be something to do with GPU acceleration. Just toggle GPU acceleration in both SL project and IE. Sometimes when CPU loads a lot while scrolling, it just doesn't scroll correctly because of this, well, I call "lag".